# programme not running correctly on dev c++

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm new to c++ I'm trying to do a simple programme that calculates the weekly pay.  See source code below. When I run the programme it lets me enter the workHours but when I click enter the programme closes n does not proceed to the rest of the code. Not sure where I'm going wrong please help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{
     int workDays;
     float workHours, payRate, weeklyPay;

      workDays = 5;
      payRate = 38.55; 

      cout<< "Enter the number of hours worked: ";
      cin >> workHours;
      cin.ignore ();

      weeklyPay = workDays * workHours * payRate;

      cout << "Weekly Pay = ";
      cout << weeklyPay;
      cout << '\n';

       return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Did you already try debugging it?

Comment: the program closes because its done, you need to wait for a key press at the end, so it stops there

Comment: Now is a very good time to learn one of the most important tools for a programmer: The debugger. If you make a debug build (in an IDE simply select the "Debug" target or similar, in console using e.g. `gcc` add the `-g` flag), then you can run the program in a debugger and if there's a crash it will stop of the location of that crash. Now you can examine variables or the function call stack. You can also step through the code, line by line, to see what it really does.

Comment: Offtopic Quick tip: you can write 3 cout's in one: `cout << "Weekly Pay = " << weeklyPay << "\n";`

Comment: Awesome stuff managed to figure out what was missing thanks guys. Much appreciated?!

Answer (score 1):

The DevC++ doesn't pause the program after it ends you have to add this feature by yourself:

First include `conio.h`

```
#include <conio.h>
```

Then at the bottom of the main add `getch()`

```
getch();
```

Answer (score 0):

`What compiler` you are using as i am to run this code?

I am using visual studio 10 as IDE and it is working  for me.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem it seems. I'm using Dev-C++.